# OrientDB slow when browsing cluster

Tags: java, orientdb

Well what i am trying to achieve is to save pairs of words in a sentence and if the word is already there , i am trying to save a list of words against one.
To save the pairing as there could many millions as my data set file is very large , i opted for orientdb. I dont know if i am approaching it correctly but orientdb is very slow. After 8 hours of running it has only made pairs for 12000 sentences.
As far as i have checked the major slowdown was in browsing cluster.
Attached is my code, please if ant one can give any pointers over my approach.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Main m = new Main();
        m.openDatabase();
        m.readFile("train_v2.txt");
        m.closeDatabase();
    }
}

class Main {
    ODatabaseDocumentTx db;
    Map<String, Object> index;
    List<Object> list = null;
    String pairing[];
    ODocument doc;

    Main() {

    }

    public void closeDatabase() {
        if (!db.isClosed()) {
            db.close();
        }
    }

    void openDatabase() {
        db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("local:/databases/model").open("admin",
                "admin");
        doc = new ODocument("final");
    }

    public void readFile(String filename) {
        InputStream ins = null; // raw byte-stream
        Reader r = null; // cooked reader
        int i = 1;
        BufferedReader br = null; // buffered for readLine()
        try {
            String s;
            ins = new FileInputStream(filename);
            r = new InputStreamReader(ins, "UTF-8"); // leave charset out
                                                        // for
                                                        // default
            br = new BufferedReader(r);
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("" + i);
                createTermPair(s.replaceAll("[^\\w ]", "").trim());
                i++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage()); // handle exception
        } finally {
            closeDatabase();
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (Throwable t) { /* ensure close happens */
                }
            }
            if (r != null) {
                try {
                    r.close();
                } catch (Throwable t) { /* ensure close happens */
                }
            }
            if (ins != null) {
                try {
                    ins.close();
                } catch (Throwable t) { /* ensure close happens */
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTermPair(String phrase) {
        phrase = phrase + " .";
        String[] word = phrase.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length - 1; i++) {
            if (!word[i].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")
                    && !word[i + 1].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                String wordFirst = word[i].toLowerCase().trim();
                String wordSecond = word[i + 1].toLowerCase().trim();
                String pair = wordFirst + " " + wordSecond;
                checkForPairAndWrite(pair);
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkForPairAndWrite(String pair) {
        try {
            pairing = pair.trim().split(" ");

            if (!pairing[1].equalsIgnoreCase(" ")) {
                index = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                for (ODocument docr : db.browseCluster("final")) {
                    list = docr.field(pairing[0]);
                }
                if (list == null) {
                    list = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                list.add("" + pairing[1]);

                if (list.size() >= 1)
                    index.put(pairing[0], list);
                doc.fields(index);
                doc.save();
            }// for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                // System.out.println("" + list.get(i));
                // }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return;

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the meaning of the for loop that browse all the cluster and set the list variable for all the value? In this way you got only last record browsed value.

Comment: i couldnt find a better way for looping on the cluster, i knew that it has to be something with the loop but i couldnt find any better solution for getting the value from field. Can you please tell a better way to do the same. :)

Comment: I mean, browsing is ok, but with the code (list = docr.field(pairing[0])) in the for loop you're rewriting the list variable at every cycle. So what's the meaning for that? Getting last value only?

Comment: now what i actually am trying to do is to write a list for every field.
so i was thinking that may be cause i am writing a list so it will  return only one  value for every docr.field(pairing[0])

Comment: The basic purpose of this code is to make bigrams list for every word in a large set of sentences.
Saving all occurrence of bigrams in a list for a word in the orientdb.

Comment: Maybe you should do: list.add( docr.field(pairing[0]) );

Comment: alright and is there any better way to get value from a cluster for a specific term, instead of looping the whole cluster?

Comment: You can use query like RDBMS by using filters. Look at: http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Tutorial-SQL.html

Comment: Thanks alot for the help . The fetching still seems to get slow after a few hundred thousand. I guess i ll have to get a better understanding of orientdb and then i ll be changing my program's architecture. Still thanks a lot :)